# Duplicates getting inserted in data flow transformation - ADF pipeline

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

I am new to ADF. I have a sql query that I need to convert to ADF pipeline.
I have table1 in linkedserver A and table2 in Linkedserver B. I need to import data from Table1 to table2.
I have below sql query

```
select A.Id from linkedserver1.databasename.dbo.table1 A left join  linkedserver2.databasename.dbo.table2 B on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null
```

I need to convert this to pipeline
I don't want to import record that is already existing in table B. below pipline is inserting duplicate records. I tried using left join .
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need 1 more filter activity after your left join and before sink

You can use `isNull(...)` in the `Filter on` expression.
[image]